# Uniqueness of Hilbert transform as an operators from Schwartz class to bounded continuous functions on $R$. (Terry tao notes exercise)

Tags: harmonic-analysis

Let $T : S(R) \rightarrow C_b(R)$ be a continuous linear operator which maps
Schwartz functions to bounded continuous, and which commutes with translations
and dilations. Show that T is a linear multiple of the Hilbert
transform and the identity.

(Hint: first establish the existence of a tempered distribution
$K \in S(R)^*$ such that

$$Tf(x) = \left<K,\text{Trans}_{-x}f \right> \ \ \  \text{for all} \ \  f \in S(R),$$

and such that $K$ is homogeneous of degree $−1$. Restrict the action of K to
Schwartz functions on $R_+$ or $R_-$ and show that $K$ is a constant multiple
of $1/x$ on these functions.) (The claim is also true if we relax $C_b(R)$ to
$S(R)^*$, the space of tempered distributions, but this is a little trickier to prove.)

Comment: My question is: how to show this K is principal value tempered distribution?